# Outgoing $Z$-bosons in $s$-channel

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

I'm working on the process $e^-+e^+\rightarrow ZZ$, taking into account Yukawa interactions, at tree level. Below is the diagram I got for the interaction with the Higgs. I want to write its corresponding amplitude and thus need to include the polarization vectors of the outcoming Z bosons, but since they are attached to the same vertex, do the vectors have the same lorentz index $\mu$ or they I distinguish them accordingly $\epsilon^\mu$ and $\epsilon^\nu$?

[image]

Comment: How do you write the relevant HZZ vertex in the lagrangian?

Comment: @CosmasZachos the HZZ vertex will be given by $i\frac{g}{cos\theta_W}m_Zg_{\mu\nu}$. Then I guess they should have different indices. Am I correct?

Comment: ? Write the scalar term in the lagrangian.

Comment: $\frac{g}{2cos^2\theta_W }HZ^\mu Z_\mu$, is this the correct term for the HZZ vertex in the lagrangian?

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but those are gluon lines you've drawn for the $Z$ bosons. They should be electroweak lines (like a photon).

Comment: you're absolutely right, somehow i've mistaken these loopy lines with the wavy lines of the photon

Comment: The Lorentz structure is finally right. Dimension-wise, it cannot be right, so it needs a dimensional constant, but that is not part of your question.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm still a bit confused. If i raise the last lorentz index with the metric i get that the vertex is proportional to $g_{\mu\nu}HZ^\mu Z^\nu$. Doesn't that answer my questions relatively to the index to be used in the polarization vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant trilinear term in the SM lagrangian, dimensionally correct,  is 
$$
\frac{m_Z^2}{v}  H Z_\mu Z^\mu ,
$$ 
so the vertex coupling to $\epsilon_1 ^\mu$ and $\epsilon_2 ^\nu$ is
$$
\frac{ie ~m_W}{\sin \theta_w \cos^2\theta_w} g_{\mu\nu}.
$$

The two polarizations are just trivially dotted onto each other.